# Error using Xpath in Rhomobile

Tags: rhomobile

I am trying to parse XML using rexml Xpath, but facing error as const_missing: XPath in rhomobile application. can anyone give me the solution.

Below is the sample code:
 file = File.new(file_name)
        begin
            require 'rexml/document'

```
      xmldoc = REXML::Document.new(file)
      names = XPath.match(xmldoc, "//MP_HOST_NAME" )
```

Comment: Can you post the full class? Your error is mentioning that XPath is not defined (which, it's not included with the REXML library).  If you could help us understand the full context of class, that would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

in your build.yml file:

```
extensions:
- rexml
```

if using blackberry, replace rexml with rhoxml

Assuming you've done this, replace your XPath with:

```
REXML::XPath.match(xmldoc, "//MP_HOST_NAME" )
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample controller I knocked to test xml parsing
I can use the get_names method in the view then to get an array of names

```
require 'rho/rhocontroller'
require 'rexml/document'
class WebServiceTestController < Rho::RhoController

  def index
    @@get_result = ""

    Rho::AsyncHttp.get(
      :url => 'http://www.somesite.com/some_names.xml',
      #:authorization => {:type => :basic, :username => 'user', :password => 'none'},
      :callback => (url_for :action => :httpget_callback),
      :authentication => {
        :type => :basic,
        :username => "xxxx",
        :password => "xxxx"
      },
      :callback_param => "" )
    render :action => :wait
  end

  def get_res
    @@get_result
  end

  def get_error
    @@error_params
  end

  def httpget_callback
    if @params["status"] != "ok"
      @@error_params = @params
      WebView.navigate( url_for(:action => :show_error) )
    else
      @@get_result = @params["body"]

      begin
 #       require "rexml/document"

        @@doc = REXML::Document.new(@@get_result)
#        puts "doc : #{doc}"
      rescue Exception => e
#        puts "Error: #{e}"
        @@get_result = "Error: #{e}"
      end

      WebView.navigate( url_for(:action => :show_result) )
    end
  end

  def show_error
    render :action => :error, :back => '/app'
  end

  def show_result
    render :action => :index, :back => "/app"
  end

  def get_doc
    @@doc
  end

  def get_names
    names = []
    REXML::XPath.each( get_doc, "//name_or_whatever_you_are_looking_for") do |element|
      names << element.text
    end
    names
  end

end
```

ensure that rhoxml is set in the build.yml file rather than rexml this works fine and it's a little faster